# Javascript Letter Frequency Counter Issue

Tags: javascript, html

there!
I am building a letter frequency counter and want to make it count word frequency as well, the problem is:
I built my code but couldn't make it work.

What I want is: Input: "Help me with this code."
the output should be: "h" 2, "e": 3, "l": 1, ...
"help" : 1, "me" : 1, ...

Here is where I am stuck at:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("countButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {});


let counter = () => {
  let typedText = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
  typedText = typedText.toLowerCase().value;
  typedText = typedText.replace(/[^a-z'\s]+/g, "");

  for (let i = 0; i < typedText.length; i++) {
    currentLetter = typedText[i];

    const letterCounts = {};

    if (letterCounts[currentLetter] === undefined) {
      letterCounts[currentLetter] = 1;
    } else {
      letterCounts[currentLetter]++;
    }

    for (let letter in letterCounts) {
      const span = document.createElement("span");
      const textContent = `"${letter}": ${letterCounts[letter]}, `;
      span.innerText = textContent;
      const letters = document.getElementById("lettersDiv");
      letters.appendChild(span);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="entry">
    <h1>Type your text:</h1>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="60" id="textInput"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="countButton">Count frequency!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="lettersDiv"></div>
  <div id="wordsDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: please add details about what you want to do - maybe input and output example

Comment: added more detais. :D

Comment: so you need to call `counter()` in the `click` function

Comment: tried that but it seems to fail with no error codes in the console

Comment: I suggest you step through your code by hand one line at a time to understand exactly what it is doing. For example, what does typedText.toLowerCase().value evaluate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made several changes to your code.

1. Shifted `letterCounts` object outside the for loop.
2. Removed `.value` from `typedText.toLowerCase().value`
3. Empty the `lettersDiv` upon each button click so that previous counts doesn't stay there
4. Put `for (let letter in letterCounts){...}` loop outside `for (let i = 0; i < typedText.length; i++) {...}` loop

```js
let counter = () => {
  let typedText = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
  typedText = typedText.toLowerCase();
  typedText = typedText.replace(/\s+/g, "");
  document.getElementById("lettersDiv").textContent = "";
  const letterCounts = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < typedText.length; i++) {
    let currentLetter = typedText[i];

    if (letterCounts[currentLetter] === undefined) {
      letterCounts[currentLetter] = 1;
    } else {
      letterCounts[currentLetter] = letterCounts[currentLetter] + 1;
    }
  }
  for (let letter in letterCounts) {
      const span = document.createElement("span");
      const textContent = `"${letter}": ${letterCounts[letter]}, `;
      span.innerText = textContent;
      const letters = document.getElementById("lettersDiv");
      letters.appendChild(span);
    }
}

const button = document.getElementById("countButton");
button.addEventListener("click", counter);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="entry">
    <h1>Type your text:</h1>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="60" id="textInput"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="countButton">Count frequency!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="lettersDiv"></div>
  <div id="wordsDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @techysharnav ! Now I see what I was doing wrong! You helped me alot, I was looking for the way to empty the div for another test!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const button = document.getElementById("countButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {counter()});


let counter = () => {
  let typedText = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
  typedText = typedText.toLowerCase();
  typedText = typedText.replace(/[^a-z'\s]+/g, "");

  const letterCounts = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < typedText.length; i++) {
    currentLetter = typedText[i];

    if (letterCounts[currentLetter] === undefined) {
      letterCounts[currentLetter] = 1;
    } else {
      letterCounts[currentLetter]++;
    }
  }
  for (let letter in letterCounts) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    const textContent = `"${letter}": ${letterCounts[letter]}, `;
    span.innerText = textContent;
    const letters = document.getElementById("lettersDiv");
    letters.appendChild(span);
  }
}
```